# C++ array error about does not match a type

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code and I get the following error.

**Code**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
//...
using namespace std;
main(){
vector<int> arrayi;
int i = 999;          // some integer value
arrayi.reserve(10);    // make room for 10 elements
arrayi.push_back(i);
cout<<arrayi.capacity()<<endl;
cout<<arrayi.size()<<endl;
}
```

**Error**

||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
error: 'arrayi' does not name a type|

error: 'arrayi' does not name a type|

error: 'cout' does not name a type|

error: 'cout' does not name a type|

||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

where did I go wrong??

Comment: Your code is not in a function? Probably, I don't know if you removed `main()` to save space or not.

Comment: Please edit your question to add error text into it instead of link

Comment: `main` has return type `int`. Other than that, there is no obvious error in this example. It compiles fine once you add `int` before `main`. Please make sure the example you provide actually produces the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have expression [statements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements) in the namespace-/file-[scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). Only declaration statements are allowed.

Declare a function, and write the expressions in the block scope of that function. In particular, I suggest declaring the [main function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function), because a C++ program must contain one. Main function is the entry point of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is in global namespace, it should go in a function like `main()`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arrayi;
    int i = 999;           // some integer value
    arrayi.reserve(10);    // make room for 10 elements
    arrayi.push_back(i);
    std::cout << arrayi.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << arrayi.size() << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/4anTFb)